# How to disable OK button in `gbasicdialog()` instance of gWidgets2?

Tags: r, window, gwidgets

Consider:

```
fix_df <- function(DF, ...) {
  dfname <- deparse(substitute(DF))
  w <- gbasicdialog(..., handler=function(h,...) {
    assign(dfname, df[,], .GlobalEnv)
  })
  g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
  glabel("Edit a data frame", cont=g)
  df <- gdf(DF, cont=g, expand=TRUE)
  size(w) <- c(400, 400)
  out <- visible(w)
}

m <- mtcars[1:3, 1:4]
fix_df(m)
```

How can I programmatically disable the OK button in `w`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `do.buttons` argument to not show the buttons. To access the button requires digging into the internals. You can see how that is hacked in where `do.buttons` is implemented in `gWidgets2RGtk2`.